# python/django: How can I convert json string to html format?

Tags: python, html, django, json

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I really appreciate it if there's such a thing.

I have a json object that contains a json string that another program returns which is a html code. However, when I render it to the django template, it's just a big trunk of string. I wonder if there's such tool in python/django that can convert a string into "html format" text. Thanks.

Edit: I use `json.loads()` to load the output of the other program, and extract the useful information, then return it to template. In template I simply use django template syntax like `{{ v.response }}` to show it. After that the page looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Please include a sample of the data, and of the resulting output. How are you including the data in your template?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I added some more description in Edit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know the string is safe, you can mark as such so that the template engine will not auto-escape it: try `{{ v.response|safe }}`.